# Is it possible to disable iPhone sounds and vibrations when the phone is unlocked?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, text, vibrate

I have been chatting extensively on my iPhone via text messages. I always have my phone on silent and the vibrations seem to really run down the battery. It's a waste because a lot of the time I have the person's text window open already and I don't need a non-visual alert. But if I have the phone locked in my pocket I want it. I assume the answer is no but is there any way to disable sounds or vibrations when the phone is unlocked? Even though Apple can be stingy with settings this seems like a worthwhile one to add doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

When it's unlocked, you could simply mute it, and remember to unmute it when you remove it from your eyesight - Turn off "Vibrate on Silent" in `Settings > Sounds`.  Only a workaround, but perhaps useful.